# Webpack index.html link css import

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader, webpack-3

I have webpack project. I want in my index.html file to add a link to css from a package. For example :

<link href="bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.cssײ>

How is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Make "import 'bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css';" that it function.